# How to increment numaric values only of alphanumeric values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
proId = 'nam001'
```

I want to  increment numeric values only. That should be like this 'nam002', 'nam003'.
How to do this?

Comment: do you get the original `nam001` as a value from somewhere else? or do you create it in your own code?

Comment: Is `nam001` a string or a variable name?

Comment: split it, increment it, put it back to gether. Splitting here could mean string slicing

Comment: @Adam.Er8, 
Actually  I set the proId = 'nam001' manually, from next time that should be increment.

Comment: so you can use a simple loop over an int range, look at [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) for padding with `0`, and just slap it at the end of `nam`...

Comment: @ Roberto Caboni, it is a string- 'nam001'  .

Comment: @Adam.Er8, Please give me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you asked nicely :D

You can use the simplest `for` loop, with [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to pad with zeroes, then add it to the `'nam'` prefix like this:

```py
for i in range(1,11):
    proId = 'nam' + str(i).zfill(3)
    print(proId) # or do whatever you need with it...
```

Output:

```
nam001
nam002
...
nam009
nam010
```

Comment: no need to zfill - use string formatting: `f"nam{i:03}"`